# Read Nested JSON object in typescript in NestJs

Tags: json, nestjs

I am new to type script and Nested JSON Object structure. I am using NestJs . Here is my JSON request

```
{
    "recipes": [
        {
            "recipe_id": 1,
            "ingredients": [
                {
                    "ingredient_id": 2,
                    "quantity": 4,
                    "unit": "g",
                    "nutrients": [
                        {
                            "nutrient_id": 1,
                            "quantity": 2,
                            "unit": "g"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "ingredient_id": 3,
                    "quantity": 4,
                    "unit": "g",
                    "nutrients": [
                        {
                            "nutrient_id": 2,
                            "quantity": 2,
                            "unit": "g"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "recipe_id": 2,
            "ingredients": [
                {
                    "ingredient_id": 4,
                    "quantity": 4,
                    "unit": "g",
                    "nutrients": [
                        {
                            "nutrient_id": 4,
                            "quantity": 2,
                            "unit": "g"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "ingredient_id": 5,
                    "quantity": 4,
                    "unit": "g",
                    "nutrients": [
                        {
                            "nutrient_id": 5,
                            "quantity": 2,
                            "unit": "g"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is my code to read above json request

```
public async createMealRecipe(request) {
        try{
            const ingredientData = request.recipes.flatMap(item => {
                return item.ingredients.map(({ingredient_id, quantity, unit}) =>{
                    return {
                        recipe_id: item.recipe_id, ingredient_id, quantity, unit
                    }
                })
            });
            const nutrientData = request.recipes.flatMap(item1 => {
                return item1.nutrients.map(({nutrient_id, quantity, unit}) =>{
                    return {
                        recipe_id: item1.recipe_id, nutrient_id, quantity, unit
                    }
                })
            });
            console.log(ingredientData);
            console.log(nutrientData);
        }catch(e) {
            console.log('e', e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

console.log(ingredientData); is working fine, but when i try to log this console.log(nutrientData); i am getting `map undefined` error . Please correct me. Actually I am new to nestjs / typescript.

```
EDIT: `So instead of map function is there any possibility to traverse using forEach loop ?`
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `request.recipes.flatMap(item1 => {` doesn't give you an object representing a nutrient. `item1` in this case is a recipe such as

```json
{
  recipe_id: 1,
  ingredients: [
    { ingredient_id: 2, quantity: 4, unit: 'g', nutrients: [Array] },
    { ingredient_id: 3, quantity: 4, unit: 'g', nutrients: [Array] }
  ]
}
```

which also makes sense because the loop is no different than the one in which you loop over recipes above. If you'd like to loop over the nutrients of each recipe, you need to loop over the `item1.ingredients` array first. An example of this would be something like the following:

```
const nutrientData = request.recipes.flatMap(recipe => {
  return recipe.ingredients.map(({ ingredient_id, quantity, unit, nutrients }) => {
    return nutrients.map(({ nutrient_id, quantity, unit }) => {
      return {
          recipe_id: recipe.recipe_id, nutrient_id, quantity, unit
      };
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, Is there any possibility using forEach loop ? please guide me