# Parse JSON string into TypeScript object

Tags: json, typescript, nestjs

I am trying to parse JSON in [specific format](https://dicom.nema.org/dicom/2013/output/chtml/part18/sect_F.2.html) into TypyScript objects, here is a sample data:

```
[
    {
        "00101002": 
        {
            "vr": "SQ",
            "Value": 
            [
                {
                    "00100020": 
                    {
                        "vr": "LO",
                        "Value": [ "54321" ]
                    },
                    "00100021": 
                    {
                        "vr": "LO",
                        "Value": [ "Hospital B" ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "00100020": 
                    {
                        "vr": "LO",
                        "Value": [ "24680" ]
                    },
                    "00100021":
                    {
                        "vr": "LO",
                        "Value": [ "Hospital C" ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

What would be the (best) way to parse it into TypeScript object to sink it into DB later on? I am using [NestJS framework](https://nestjs.com/).

Comment: Bonus (but unrelated) reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74360766/read-nested-json-object-in-typescript-in-nestjs

Answer (score 0):

Infinite depth:

```
type TItem  = {
    [x:string]: {
      vr: string;
      Value: Array<string | TItem>;
    }
}
```

:)